# Struct value changes after passing to method

Tags: c, struct, pcap

I am writing a packet parser using libpcap and encounter strange behaviour when trying to read the packet length form the pcap header.

The first `printf` statement below prints out the correct packet length, whereas the second one prints out a number such as 362791.

```
struct pcap_pkthdr header;
pcap_t *handle;
const u_char *packet;

...

    while((packet = pcap_next(handle, &header)) != NULL) {
        printf("[%d]\n", header.len);   
        process_packet(&header, packet);
    }

...
}

void process_packet(struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet) {
    printf("[%d] %d bytes\n", header->ts, header->len);
}
```

The definition of `struct pcap_pkthdr` is:

```
struct pcap_pkthdr {
    struct timeval ts; /* time stamp */
    bpf_u_int32 caplen; /* length of portion present */
    bpf_u_int32 len; /* length this packet (off wire) */
};
```

The prototype for `pcap_next` is `u_char *pcap_next(pcap_t *p, struct pcap_pkthdr *h)`

Is there any reason that this is happening?

Comment: What's the prototype of the `pcap_next()` function? What are `handle` and `packet`?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the struct?

Comment: I have added the prototype for `pcap_next`, the declarations of `handle` and `packet`, and the definition of `struct pcap_pkthdr`.

Comment: Can you show the definition for bpf_u_int32?

Comment: As far as I can tell `typedef u_int bpf_u_int32; `

Comment: You should be using the printf format specifier for unsigned integers: `%u`.

Comment: What OS and compiler is this?  Have you tried `printf("[%d]\n", (int)header->len);`?  (Or using `%u` as the format specifier?)  This smells like a mismatch between the size of `header->len` and what `printf` is expecting...

Comment: @Nemo, but if this where the case, it would be bad in both printf statements... no?

Comment: Oops, just realised I forgot to include the bit where I print out the timestamp also. =/ But in realising this, it turns out that if I remove the timestamp, it prints the length properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the root problem is that in the code

`printf("[%d] %d bytes\n", header->ts, header->len);`

the `ts` data section whose type is `struct timeval` is not just a simple integer data, or at least the sizeof(timeval) is not the same as sizeof(int). This will cause the printf uses the wrong address offset when trying to fetch the second parameter in a var arguments list.

So I think `printf("[%d] %d bytes\n", header->len, header->ts );` should work correct, but you cannot simply exchange them.

Comment: Yea, it looks like it is something like this, removing the timestamp completely solved the problem so I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

your C code looks valid, I can't see any problem with the syntax.  So it might be something not related to C itself.

The only thing that currently comes to mind is that something is running concurrently in the background and slamming your struct.  I don't know a lot about pcap, so I can't help you with the specifics...

BUT, When I have such oddities, I usually create a stats function which prints out every conceivable thing about a structure... and call the stats function everywhere... this is like a mini in-line unit test.

I'd like you to refurbish your code into this and try it out:

```
void hdr_stats(struct pcap_pkthdr *header){
    unsigned int i;
    printf("address of header:  %p\n", header);

    printf("caplen:             %d\n", header->caplen);
    i = header->caplen;
    printf("caplen:             %d\n", i);

    printf("len:                %d\n", header->len);
    i = header->len;
    printf("len:                %d\n", i);

    //-------
    // add header->ts.xxxx debugging here, might give other clues...
    //-------
}

...

    while((packet = pcap_next(handle, &header)) != NULL) {
        printf("[%d]\n", header.len);   
        hdr_stats(&header);
        process_packet(&header, packet);
        hdr_stats(&header);
    }

...

void process_packet(struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet) {
    hdr_stats(header);
    printf("[%d]\n", header->len);
    hdr_stats(header);
}
```

this might help you corner your bug.

Comment: I use both debugger and tracing, but sometimes, tracing gives easier comparison options.

Answer (score 0):

... are you comparing apples to oranges?

```
/* header.len in brackets */
printf("[%d]\n", header.len); 

/* header->ts in brackets */
printf("[%d] %d bytes\n", header->ts, header->len);
```